# Relative import module

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a project:

```
    package\
    │
    └───┐ package\
        │
        ├──── __init__.py
        └───┐ subpackage\
            │
            ├──── __init__.py
            └──── spam.py
```

in `subpackage\__init__.py` I can import `spam` via:

```
    from package.subpackage.spam import eggs, beans
```

...or...

```
    from .spam import eggs, beans
```

The latter is robust to changing the name of the `package`, which is useful in my current case of a project in early development.

The problem arises when I don't want to actually export anything from `spam`, I just want it to perform its initialisation logic.

For instance, the following does not work.

```
    import .spam
```

(I am using `PyCharm`, which identifies the error, if this is relevant.)

Is there an alternative or standard way to import in this case?

Comment: did you import eggs, beans in `__init__.py` near `spam`?

Comment: have you tried using `from . import spam`?

Comment: @Gahan think that's the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In python imports are like below:

```
from <path-to-file> import <file-name-or-class/method/variable>
```

So when you are writing `import .spam` it will look for `.spam.py` means instead of looking for `spam.py` it is looking for `.spam.py` so you can import it correctly as below:

```
from . import spam
```